# Android Bitmap loosing image resolution

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I am developing an application for android and it contains several images and I have to get them from drawable, so I am using bitmap for them to avoid out of memory exception by rescaling them, but the problem is when rescaling, the resolution (/quality) of the image is reduced. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Do you really get a 'out of memory exception'? How many images are you dealing with? If you reduce the resolution, of course it will loose quality... the way you ask your question may not be the right way for stackoverflow....

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a reference to the original byte array and check your bitmap size against it but I would just use pngs in the appropriate drawable folders. Rescaling/reloading the image yourself and checking for quality could be much more memory hungry in a garbage collected language.
Let android do it's thing..

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can avoid the loss in quality is by scaling the image proportionately in terms of width and height.

For eg : if your resolution is 100x80 try reducing it to 5x:4x . That will somewhat preserve the quality.